# Do colour schemas interfere with settings from iterm2, oh-my-zsh and vim?

Tags: vim, oh-my-zsh, color-management, iterm2

There are so many color schemes for terminal environment, themes for shell and color coding schema for vim. I wonder what's the relation between them and do they interfere with each other?

For example, I'm using iterm2 terminal emulator, Oh My Zsh framework for zsh shell configuration and vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight for c++ code coloring in vim.

1. The color preset of my iterm2 is **Solarized Dark**
2. The zsh_theme of my .zhrc file is set as **apple**
3. I've followed [this](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized) page to installed the **Solarized Dark** color scheme for vim
4. For c++ code highlight enhancement I've downloaded [vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight](https://github.com/octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight)

Issues I have

1. I have 4 color related sachems so far, what's relation between them? Why 3 is needed if the entire terminal emulator has already set the color schema to **Solarized Dark**
2. The c++ color highlighting is not working at all when I open a c++ source file(I do have **filetype on** set in vim ), is it because the color schema is overwritten by the setting in list-item 3 above?